# Search Accounts using SQL Server 2008 stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, search, stored-procedures

I recently started developing/improving the way my search algorithm works. There is few different queries in the system that will use this approach. I'm new in stored procedures world and from what I researched they should improve security, performance and save some code redundancy. Here is example of what I have done in one of my stored procedures for Account search:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchAccounts] 
    @Status INT = NULL,
    @Type INT = NULL,
    @FilterBy INT = NULL,
    @Username VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Email VARCHAR(80) = NULL,
    @LastName VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @FirstName VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @FullName VARCHAR(100) = NULL   
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
    DECLARE @AccountStatus INT = @Status;
    DECLARE @AccountType INT = @Type;
    DECLARE @AccountFilter INT = @FilterBy;
    DECLARE @AccountUsername VARCHAR(50) = @Username;
    DECLARE @AccountEmail VARCHAR(80) = @Email;
    DECLARE @AccountLast VARCHAR(50) = @LastName;
    DECLARE @AccountFirst VARCHAR(50) = @FirstName;
    DECLARE @AccountFull VARCHAR(10) = @FullName; 

    SELECT 
        A.AccountID, A.FirstName, A.LastName, A.Middle, A.Email,
        A.IsUser, A.ActiveUser, A.SystemAdmin, A.AccessType, 
        A.AccessLevel, A.UserName, A.IsStaff, A.ActiveStaff, 
        A.Position AS PositionCode, M.Name AS Position
    FROM
        Accounts AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Master AS M ON M.Tblid = 'STAFF_POS'
                    AND M.Code = A.Position
    WHERE
        ( -- If Account Type is 1 (User)
         (@AccountType = 1 AND A.IsUser = 1)
         OR -- If Account Type is 2 (Staff)
         (@AccountType = 2 AND A.IsStaff = 1)
         OR -- Or if Account type is 0 (All accounts)
         (@AccountType = 0 AND 1 = 1)
        )
        AND
    (
        (-- If account type is user and Status is 1 (Active) or 0 (Inactive) or 2(pull active and inactive)
            @AccountType = 1 
            AND 
            (@AccountStatus = 0 OR @AccountStatus = 1) AND ActiveUser = @AccountStatus)
            OR
            (@AccountType = 1 AND @AccountStatus = 2 AND 1 = 1
        )
        OR
        (-- If account type is staff and Status is 1 (Active) or 0 (Inactive) or 2 (pull active and inactive)
            @AccountType = 2 
            AND 
            (@AccountStatus = 0 OR @AccountStatus = 1) AND ActiveStaff = @AccountStatus)
            OR
            (@AccountType = 2 AND @AccountStatus = 2 AND 1 = 1
        )
        OR
        (-- If account type is all pull all accounts active and inactive
            (@AccountType != 1 AND @AccountType != 2 AND 1 = 1)
        )
    )
    AND
        (       -- Filter is 1 then check user name.
         (@AccountFilter = 1 AND A.UserName LIKE '%'+@AccountUsername+'%')
         OR -- Filter is 2 then check email.
         (@AccountFilter = 2 AND A.Email = @AccountEmail)
         -- Here if filter is 3 then I should check First or Last or Full Name. 
         -- Still not sure what is the best approach to filter on the name fields.
        )
ORDER BY 
    A.LastName, A.FirstName
```

As you can see query above has few different filters. First user can choose if they want to search Users, Staff or pull All account types. Then to choose if they want to pull Active, Inactive or all records. Last thing is to pick the filter. I give them an option to search Username, Email or Name. Each Account has First, Last name. What would be a good option to search for those names? Check just one full name or I have to check first and last separately? First and Last name allow this set of characters in the Accounts form : A-Z, space, dash, apostrophe, period, comma - no other special characters

Answer (score 1):

There are probably dozens of ways to accomplish such a goal. But one way I would prefer (if I was using a query like the one presented) would be like this:

```
AND A.LNAME LIKE 
    CASE WHEN Len(@AccountLast) > 0 THEN 
        '%' + @AccountLast + '%'
    ELSE '%'
    END 
AND A.FNAME LIKE 
    CASE WHEN Len(@AccountFirst) > 0 THEN 
        '%' + @AccountFirst + '%'
    ELSE '%'
    END
```

Comment: Do you provide two input fields first and last in your interface or accept comma then separate last and first? In my opinion that can cause some problems since I'm allowing users to enter comma and period in their last name. For some last names like `Wegman, Junior`.

Comment: I usually wouldn't allow such variance in my user's inputs. But that's all personal preference. If you want to handle it, a simple addition can be made, which I have updated the code to reflect. The problem is, is a lot of this depends on how your data is housed. Like, if the data is `FULLNAME` and a person can be listed as `John Doe` as well as `Doe, John` it might put a damper on any consistant search parameters. This becomes immensely easier if your names are split up in the database, however. IMHO, if you try and accomodate every possible variation, you'll probably make your brain melt.

Comment: I have two fields in my table column `FirstName` and `LastName`. What you would suggest then? What is the most efficient way to perform search on the name in that case?

Comment: Its not necesarily more efficient per se, but you can avoid having to worry about variations with `FullName` possibilities by removing the `@AccountFull` altogether. It will limit the user's input to either using `FirstName` and/or `LastName` or neither (but using one of the other inputs), but never using a `FullName` input.

Comment: With your update answer would you prompt user with two separate fields ? I'm having trouble understanding how interface would look like for this solution.

Comment: That's the basic idea. Two optional fields, I would assume. For instance, if someone wanted to search for `John Doe`, they might input `John` into `Firstname` and `Doe` into `LastName` or whatever your inputs are driven from. Or simple `Doe` into `Lastname` leaving `FirstName` blank, it would still work as expected.